# When we use areas where routing should be placed - asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

If we have more areas in one project, where should routing values should be stored.
What should go to `Global.asax` and what in class in `AreaAreaRegistration.cs`
I don't use asp mvc often (it's still hobby) but routing makes me problems all the time :(
I must give one example that confuse me:
I have two areas and link in one area (*CityPage*) that should open page in another area.
So in my `global.asax` I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "CityPage_home",
                "{country}/{city}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", country = UrlParameter.Optional, city = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { area = "CityPage", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

And this works. But if I move "*CityPage_home*" from `global.asax` to `CityPageAreaRegistration.cs` then when I click on link that should open page in another area my application crash because code enters first in `CityPage/Home/Index` method.
I don't understand why this routing work in first case and not in another. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within in each area a file will be generated for you. For example.

`AdminArea` would contain a file named `AdminAreaRegistration`
With a method like this inside:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I like to modify this by adding a default controller.

### Action Links

Traditionally we use the following to create a link:

`@Html.ActionLink("MyLink","Index","Home",)`

To create a link to the admin area we use this:

`@Html.ActionLink("Admin Area","Index", new { area = "Admin", controller = "Home" })`

Now if you're inside the admin and want to place a link to the home page you need to do this:

`@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index", new { area="", controller = "Home })`

And finally, if you need to create custom routes you can put the area routes in the new file that is created within each area, and continue to put your non area specific routes in the normal Global.asax.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I updated question with one specific detail that make me confused on what should go where in routing. Can you please check.

Comment: You're area route needs to be prefixed with the area name like this `"CityPage/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters`

Comment: So if all my application code is in areas I don't have to put any route parameters in global.asax?
I was put route in global.asax that should open page if user is authenticated.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can put all of the routes in one file. I've been putting my area related routes in the file within the area, and my root routes in the global.asax

Answer (score 1):

based on your description. I think the link on your CityPage area doesn't match pattern `area/controller/action`
instead, it matches `controller/action`, in your case, `country/city`.

when u have the "CityPage_home" in your global.ascx, it matches the first route with action equals "home" and action equals "index". values in your url will be assigned to `country` and `city`.

but if you moved route "CityPage_home" to `CityPageAreaRegistration.cs`, then the `default` route will be picked up. as routes in `global.ascx` will be looked up first, in which case, area is `CityPage` as you set it as default.

@Nick gives u a good introduction on routing with area